# Where do I go after Team Plasma attacks in BW2?

Tags: pokemon-black-2-white-2

Team Plasma attacked Opelucid City (Black 2) and froze up the place. I must have mashed A few too many times and now they're gone and I have no idea where to go. All unexplored towns are blocked off for increasingly implausible excuses and I don't see anything else in Opelucid city to do. I beat all the plasma grunts and some named Plasma big-shot, they took the DNA Splicer, and I beat the guy blocking the exit (but I see nothing of interest past that exit).

Where do I go after getting the 7th badge? I obviously need to go stop Team Plasma but have no idea where to go now that they've left.

Comment: You should prolly just watch a quick section of a walkthrough on youtube next time for faster reference..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have defeated the *Shadow Triad* member at the gate to *Route 11*, your next stop should be [*Humilau City*](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Humilau_City), where you get the 8th badge.

You can get there via the [*Marine Tube*](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Marine_Tube) from [*Undella Town*](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Undella_Town).

This means that, from *Opelucid City*, you (… can either fly or you …) need to take [*Route 11*](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Unova_Route_11), then the [*Village Bridge*](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Village_Bridge), [*Route 12*](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Unova_Route_12), pass through [*Lacunosa Town*](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Lacunosa_Town), take [*Route 13*](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Unova_Route_13) and then arrive at *Undella Town* where you have to enter that blue downward gate. That's the entrance to the *Marine Tube*. Walking through that, you'll exit at *Humilau City*, where Hugh will greet you.